# Git rebase - trying to merge with earliest commit vs latest commit

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I am trying to rebase my branch (origin/develop) and most current code changes on top of the upstream branch (upstream develop). I used the command `git rebase -i upstream develop`. All of the commits are visible in vim and all of them are set to 'pick'.

However, when I go to resolve the merge conflict, the merge is using my second oldest commit instead of my latest commit. For example, out of commits 1-5, it is trying to rebase commit #2 onto the upstream develop instead of commit #5. So none of my newest code changes are included in the merge.

How can I set up the rebase to use the correct/latest commit? I have tried squashing my commits first, but that did not resolve the issue. Side note, the commit it keeps reverting to was a pull request if that matters.

Comment: I recommend *avoiding* `git rebase <thing1> <thing2>`, regardless of whether you're using `-i`. (However `git rebase --onto <target> <thing1>` is fine, when you need that.) The thing1+thing2 syntax here is confusing: what are you rebasing, and onto what? When using `git rebase <thing>` you're always rebasing *the current branch*, onto the *thing you named*.

Comment: The form you're using is equivalent to: `git checkout develop; git rebase -i upstream`. That might be what you want, maybe. But it tends to be confusing.

Comment: In any case, what would help others a great deal (in terms of providing an actual answer) is to include the output (perhaps snipped down to about ten or so commits) of `git log --decorate --oneline --graph develop origin/develop upstream` or similar.

Comment: Ok good to know. To answer your first question, I am trying to rebase my branch (origin/develop, which is my repo that I forked from upstream) onto the latest code in upstream (upstream/develop).

That second option is what I want, but it is using an old commit from origin/develop instead of the latest code changes.

Comment: I will try that command you listed and post more info shortly. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm I cannot get ```git log --decorate --oneline --graph develop origin/develop upstream``` to work in my terminal. It says ```fatal: ambiguous argument 'upstream': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```
I have tried a couple different combos and no success. Please let m know if I should reword that to get the required information.

Comment: Also I ended up trying ```git rebase -i origin/develop --onto upstream/develop``` and it didn't give me the option to resolve any merge conflicts. It just replaced my code with upstream/develop current code. I am very confused.

Comment: OK, if `git log` doesn't accept `upstream`, but `upstream/develop` works, that's a bit odd but not completely out of the question. But then `git rebase -i upstream` should fail as well, because `git log` and `git rebase` will treat `upstream` the same here. If `upstream` is the name of a remote, `upstream` by itself as a *revision* means `upstream/HEAD`. What does `git branch -r` print?

Comment: Here is a print out of ```git branch -r```   
origin/HEAD -> origin/develop    
  origin/develop    
  origin/master    
  origin/release     
  upstream/develop

Comment: Aha: it looks like you set up `upstream` as a *single branch* clone (`git remote add -t develop upstream <url>`). So you don't have an `upstream/HEAD`, just `upstream/develop`. The log command is then `git log --decorate --oneline --graph develop origin/develop upstream/develop` and the rebase you want will also not use `upstream` by itself.